# Writing Matrix with respect to bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \{A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})\mid A \text{ is symmetric} \} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a Linear Transformation given by the following rules.

$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = 3 + 2i$

$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = 1 - 2i$

$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = i$

Compute $\left[T\right]_{B \leftarrow A}$

where

$A = \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right \} \subset M_2(\mathbb{R})$

$B = {1 + 2i, -1 + i} \subset \mathbb{C}$

Workings:

Let $X = 1+2i$

Let $Y = -1+i$

$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = 3 + 2i = \frac{5}{3} X + \frac{-4}{3}Y$

$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = 1 - 2i = \frac{-1}{3}X + \frac{4}{3}Y$

$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = i = \frac{1}{3}X + \frac{1}{3}Y$

So the matrix is:

$\frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 5 & -1 & 1 \\ -4 & 4 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I'm wondering if what I did was correct.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does $[T]_{B\leftarrow A}$ mean?

Comment: @Myath Matrix of $T$, $B$ from $A$.